# Cortar con Javascript un String indicando Strings como incio y como final

Tags: javascript, string

Tengo un `string` que contiene código `HTML` con tags `<img>` en él, necesito crear un array con los src de cada `img` pero no puedo indicarle por números dónde cortar, pues no conozco dónde aparece el tag `img` ni dónde termina

```html
<p>Hola, esto es un ejemplo<img src="./img-uploads/345753e8-bba6-d75f-3f0f-0f4d0b9bd493.jpg" style="width: 757px;">&nbsp;más texto de prueba<img src="./img-uploads/48deeb1c-a32e-cc28-76b4-e59806c7b1d5.jpg" style="width: 50px;"><br></p>
```

Mi idea es encontrar como inicio  `<img src="` y como final, el siguiente caracter en orden que sería `"`,  pues lo que genera este código es un editor y el estilo añadido variará siempre.

---

Lo he solucionado de una manera un poco rara pero funciona para encontrar en **cualquier** string un trozo usando como índice pedazos de `string` que lo rodeen

Gracias a [Lois6b por su ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44858/127), en lo que busco ahora mismo es la respuesta correcta, sin embargo, dejo el código por si alguien quiere hacer algo similar sin poder usar getElementsByTagName.

```js
var string = '<p>Hola, esto es un ejemplo<img src="./img-uploads/345753e8-bba6-d75f-3f0f-0f4d0b9bd493.jpg" style="width: 757px;">&nbsp;más texto de prueba<img src="./img-uploads/48deeb1c-a32e-cc28-76b4-e59806c7b1d5.jpg" style="width: 50px;"><br></p>'
var resultado = [];
var ultimo = -1;
do {
    var n = string.indexOf('<img src="',ultimo+1); // img
        ultimo=n;
    var m = string.indexOf('"',ultimo+10) // comillas

    if(n!=-1)
    resultado.push(string.slice(n+10, m));  //+10 por el tamaño de <img src= 
    ultimo=n;
} while (n!=-1);

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: me alegro ser de ayuda. mira mi edit para que veas la diferencia entre `.src` y `.getAttribute("src")`

Comment: Hola @JeanRodríguez. Deberías publicar tu solución como **respuesta**, y no como parte de la pregunta... Sin embargo, ¿por qué no podrías usar `.getElementsByName`?. Cualquier string se puede analizar como DOM utilizando [document.implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso puedes usar la funcion [`getElementsByTagName("img");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) que devuelve una colección de elementos, en este caso cuya Tag sea `img`.

Iteras por los elementos y para cada uno, sacas el atributo `src` con `.getAttribute("src");` para que te saque literalmente lo que contiene ese atributo. En tu caso, sacaria la URL relativa sin incluir el `http://...`

Si usas `.src` a secas sacaría la URL completa

```js
var elementos= document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imagenesSRC =  new Array (elementos.length);
for(var i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
    console.log(elementos[i].getAttribute("src"));
    imagenesSRC[i] = elementos[i].getAttribute("src");
}
```

```html
<p>Hola, esto es un ejemplo<img src="./img-uploads/345753e8-bba6-d75f-3f0f-0f4d0b9bd493.jpg" style="width: 757px;">&nbsp;más texto de prueba<img src="./img-uploads/48deeb1c-a32e-cc28-76b4-e59806c7b1d5.jpg" style="width: 50px;"><br></p>
```